# Test for independent but not identically distributed time-series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stochastic-processes

So far, runs test or bds test are doing OK with i.i.d data but not so for independent but **not** identically distributed data set based on my practical experiences with them. Are there any other tests that have good properties at test these non-i.i.d data stream?

Comment: This question is not self-contained enough, in its present form, to be answerable. I think it would be helpful to supply a little more explanation and context.

Comment: @cardinal Well, I am mostly interested in finding a test to test time-series data against a zero-mean and independantly distrubted stochastic processes (for instance, a random variable at time t: Xt~N(0, f(t)), where f(t) is some non-constant function), practical experiences shows BDS and runs tests works poorly in such cases, as the authors of these methods admitted.